# How long does a Postal Check (postal order) take to clear?

Tags: united-kingdom, postal-order

How long does a postal order take to clear? 7 days? Or is it instant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncrossed postal orders can be turned directly into cash and thus definitely take no time to clear.

Crossed postal orders have to be paid into a bank account, and so it's possible the bank would take some time to clear them. However they can't be rejected because of insufficient funds, as the sender already paid for it.

I don't have any personal experience of them and in particular I'm not quite sure what happens if you pay in a postal order that either already has been or is subsequently reported lost or stolen. The [Post Office FAQ](http://www.postoffice.co.uk/postal-orders-faqs) is my main source of information.

Comment: what is a "crossed postal order"? Is it a UK-specific term? Haven't run across it in the States :)

Comment: There's a general concept of "crossing" an instrument like a postal order or cheque in the UK, which basically means that you have to be the named recipient of the instrument in order to use it. I've fixed the FAQ link in my answer, that has a bit more info too.